# getting the max value of a list of dictionaries where multiple values exist in a dictionary

Tags: javascript

I have a list of dictionaries that look something like this:

```
activityType: "message"
actorFirstName: "name"
actorHeadline: ""
actorId: 131659821
actorLastName: "last"
actorVectorImage: 
i18nLastModifiedRelative: "24 days ago"
lastModified: 1561549463000
```

I want to check through all of the dictionaries in the list and find the most recent `lastModified` timestampe where the `actorId: 131659821` && `activityType: "message"`

I was thinking of checking each key, in a forEach loop, but that would only help if I just needed to check 1 key:value.

i tried something like:

```
  inmailList.forEach((inmail) => {
        Object.keys(inmail).forEach((key) => {
            if (inmail[key] === 'message') 
        })
    })
```

This just tells me if one value is "message", but it doesn't check to see the actorId

Is there a way to check multiple key/value's at once?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried iterating through the dictionary looking at individual keys, but I can't check multiple keys at once without setting a bunch of true/false states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// filter
let filteredData = inmailList.filter(activity => activity.actorId === 131659821 
    && activity.activityType === 'message');

// sort descending
filteredData.sort((a, b) => b.lastModified - a.lastModified);

// take first
let mostRecent = filteredData[0];
```

Comment: oooh, I see. filter & sort instead of trying to use Math.Max. That makes sense!

Comment: You can chain this of course, but broke it out into steps.